# Kotlin: Typeconverter for other class type

Tags: android, kotlin, typeconverter

I have made a room database, and this is the error I get:

[image]

This is my Image class:

```
@Parcelize
data class Image(
    @SerializedName("src") var productImgPath: String
) : Parcelable
```

this is my type converter

```
   @TypeConverter
fun imgFromString2(value: String): Image {
    val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<Image>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson(value, listType)
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `value`? seems it is incorrect JSON

Comment: try use list of String instead of list of Image.also print the `value` via Log.d()..inside `imgFromString2` so we can have better picture.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put this line of code. I want to convert this but it keeps giving me an error: can't put in the database, try an typeconverter for it.

```
 @SerializedName("image") var imagePath: Image,
```